# Question about select UITableViewCell fields

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've a custom UITableViewCell like this:

```
+--------------------------+
| username                 |
|                          |
|      --- <image> --      |
|                          |
|                <like it> |
+--------------------------+
```

It display an username, an image and a button "Like it" to like image.
I don't want that the entire cell is selectable, I want a user can tap on "username" to see a new view that show username information. The same for image, when user tap on image, he could see the image in a new view.

Now I can only select my entire cell. How can I implement something like this?

Thanks.

When you click on the username you'll see a view for user information. The entire cell is not selectable.
[image]

Comment: I want something like the screenshot above, look.

Comment: use three diffrent button on cell and according to that button perfome action , if you need i can send you code for that table view

Comment: Ok GhostRider, when you want.

Comment: @GhostRider can you give me the code for that table view please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)You keep cell selectionstyle as none,don't implement anything in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.
2)Use Three separate buttons for name,image,and like it.(because you can get event by clicking on the button). And in the registered method for button navigate to its corresponding view.

Comment: Yeah, thinked this me too. But my problem is, when user tap on an image or an username, how can I know what was tapped? When I click on "john" how can I navigate to "username view detail" with john details?

Comment: Do you know how to register method for event on button?? Here check this my giving you example:

Comment: yeah, you can dynamically add actions to the images + buttons.  

i.e.
[likeItButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

Comment: [likeItButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown]; but not forget to set tag for that button because according to tag you will access value of that cell,

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender{  
 UIButton *currentButton = (UIButton*)sender;
 if(currentButton==imageButton)
 {
      //navigate to image detail;
 {
 else if(currentButton==nameButton)
 {
     //navigate to user detail;
  }
  else if(currentButton==likeButton)
{
     //implement code for like button;
}
}
```

Comment: Ok, here's ok. But now should I use NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superview indexPathForCell: self]; for determine in which cell is happened the event?

Comment: assign tag to button with indexpath.row ,then in buttonClicked method check currentButton tag.

Answer (score 0):

Write your cell-class in a way that you fill it with content with a method like `setEntry:(MyEntryType*)entry`, so that it can remember the entry. Also give it a delegate-property for a custom protocol. The cell sets the target of each button within it to itself, like `[nameButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(namePressed:)...]`, `[likeButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(likePressed:)...]`. So if the user presses for instance a like button, the corresponding cell gets notified and calls its delegate with `[delegate entryLiked:theCellEntry]`. I hope you get the idea.